# Is it possible to pass as a parameter to a method an object with its own parameters

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I am trying to streamline the way that I create views in my application (wpf mvvm) and as I learn more about it so I see better ways of doing things.  Now I'm looking to streamline the way that the views are loaded.

Put simply I have  main window that contains a docksite that hosts documentwindows. Rather than having several methods to create these windows I'd like to refactor them into one if possible.

So let's say That I have a usercontrolA that's a control to enter persons. I'd like to pass the control to my method and have it use that parameter as part of the document instantiation. so in pseudo code terms:

```
CreateAviewButtonClickCommand
  CreateNewView(userControlA)
End

Private Sub CreateNewView(view As Object) 
    <create the document window here using view as one of the parameters>
End Sub
```

Now lets suppose that I want to do the same with usercontrolB, but unlike usercontrolA this one needs to have its own parameter so , again in pseudocode the CreateNewView Method would be more like this;

```
Private Sub CreateNewView(view(with its own parameter) As Object) 
    <create the document window here using view as one of the parameters>
End Sub
```

Quite possibly with all the additional typecasting that would be required this might be more trouble than its worth but I'm curious as to whether it could be done.

Comment: There is not enough to give an example but yes you can do this I do it all the time.  LocalActivityLog.AddActivityDetail(New ActivityDetail("", New OracleNumber(CInt(value)), startDateString, ""))